# When running npm test in react Jest is giving me the message below and All I am trying to do is run the test it comes by default inside App.test.js

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users.....\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node' from 'grpc_extension.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
    './grpc_extension.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx',
```

'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

```
See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string     

However, Jest was able to find:
    './client_interceptors.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx',
```

'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

```
See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string     

However, Jest was able to find:
    '../api/api-firebase.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx',
```

PASS  src/App.test.js
FAIL  src/pages/InventoryItems.test.js
● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\el_mo\Boom\BoomAdmin\boom-platform-admin-portal\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node' from 'grpc_extension.js'

However, Jest was able to find:
    './grpc_extension.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx',
```

'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

```
See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string     

However, Jest was able to find:
    './client_interceptors.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx',
```

'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

```
See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string     

However, Jest was able to find:
    '../api/api-firebase.js'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx',
```

'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

```
See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

However, Jest was able to find:
    './InventoryItems.test.js'
    './InventoryItems.tsx'

You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js'js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:32:13)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.856s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Comment: You might have a direct file import with extension in your test suits

Comment: Please always use the corresponding language/technology tag you're using. This way you'll attract more relevant people and those who ignore particular tags won't be encountering irrelevant (to them) topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved it!!
I had to downgrade node's version, then I had to re-install react-scripts.
The node version that I used was 6.14.8